# Add counter button in odoo to update field value by 1

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, business-logic, odoo-10

I want to add counter in report. I mean, everytime I click print button, report has to be printed with +1 increment, written like Reprinted 1, Reprinted 2, Reprinted 3 and so on. Do you have any idea about solving this kind of technique. If it is impossible, I have another idea but I don't know how to do that either. And that is: Add a field in a form and every time I click custom print button, the field value will be increased by 1. And that updated field will be printed in a report.
I am still a learning boy. Please reply with example.

What I have is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5LDX.png)

```
<record id="apple_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Apple Form</field>
    <field name="model">se.apple</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <header>
                <button name="print_report" string="Print Apple" type="object"/>
            </header>
            <h1 class="dexter">This is Dexter</h1>
            <sheet>
                <group name="group_top">
                    <group name="group_left">
                        <field name="apple_name"/>
                    </group>
                    <group name="group_right">
                        <field name="apple_price"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group name="group_bottom">
                    <field name="apple_description"/>
                    <field name="apple_remarks"/>
                </group>
                <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
                    <t t-name="custom_btn">
                        <button string="Custom Button">Custom Button</button>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you suggested, you could make an invisible field in the model. Then you inherit the print method and make it increment that invisible field. Since the report will have the entire object available, you can just access that invisible field in your report.

Comment: could you give me an example